# Change timezone of timezone-aware object in django

Tags: django, timezone

I have a timezone aware object:

```
date = timezone.now()
```

and then I am getting the user's timezone using some middleware, so I have it as a string, like:

```
tz = "America/New_York"
```

This is probably a really simple question but I have not been able to find the answer anywhere: How do I change the timezone of the date object to the user's timezone? I tried `date.localize(tz)` but that gave me an error. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a timezone object, then use `astimezone()`

```
    import pytz
    timezone = pytz.timezone(tz)
    your_date_with_usertimezone = date.astimezone(timezone)
```